# SSIS Error "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 2)."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am creating a flat text  file to DB dump in SSIS with following column
`File Data` :

```
firstname,lastname,DOB,Inverstment (all string 50)
```

SQL Server table:

```
ID (int sequence type as default)   
FirstName (varchar(50)) 
LastName (varchar(50))  
DateofBirth (datetime)  
Inverstment, AgeofInvestment
```

Flow:

```
flatfile source ---> data conversion (DOB to [DT_DBDATE],Inverstment to [DT_CY])
---> Derived Column (to calculate "AgeofInvestment") 
---> OLE DB Destination
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [OLE DB Destination [51]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The statement has been terminated."
>
> An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 2)."

Note: checked data with data viewer which is passed to destination seems correct. I'm able to insert from SSMS.

[image: Data Flow Task]

[image: Project Progress Screen Shot]

Comment: This is not an SSIS issue, it's a database issue. Do you have any triggers on the target table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No

Comment: What is the OleDB Destination command?  Is it a stored procedure?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft   not a command or stored procedure . In OLE DB Destination Data Access mode is "Table or View"  ,  Connection is created with Native OLE DB\SQL server Native Client  11.0

Comment: Then it's probably a trigger, or a calculated column. Perhaps inserting into a view.  Use Profiler to see the calls at the database and see what's really happening.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  I removed "ID (int sequence type as default)  "  from table  every thing work perfect ,need to debug why column filled by sequence object having issues  when data insert by SSIS,